# Separate two types of polymorphic association in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have polymorphic association between Teams and Player that belongs to Tags and each tag belongs to an article.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :article_id, :tagable_id, :tagable_type

  belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Since both teams and players have different fields how can I separate the two in my article show page?

This doesn't work

```
  <% @article.tags.each do |tag| %>
      <%= tag.nickname if tag.tagable_type = "Player" %>
      <%= tag.name if tag.tagable_type = "Team" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<% @article.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.nickname if tag.tagable_type == "Player" %>
  <%= tag.name if tag.tagable_type == "Team" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks figured it out, had to have tag.tagable.nickname instead of just tag.nickname.   <% @article.tags.each do |tag| %>
      <%= tag.tagable.nickname if tag.tagable_type == "Player" %>
      <%= tag.tagable.name if tag.tagable_type == "Team" %>
  <% end %>